# TinyMce attribute invalid_elements does not prevent from indicated tags to be used or pasted, why is this happening?

Tags: tinymce

I've been trying to use the invalid_elements property inside the window.tinymce.init object but to no avail, invalid elements and valid_elements (i.e.  ,  , etc) keeps apearing if i paste something or if i select the bold option for instance. I also tried the  paste_word_valid_elements: 'b,strong,i,em,h1,h2', property, without any positive results.

Also, in this site https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/demo/valid-elements/ you can try the properties i mentioned above and they still not work... why is that??

is this ment to be this way, is it a bug or am i missing something while coding it.

this is the object i'm passing to the init method:

````
    selector: `#${(target as HTMLDivElement).id}`,
    plugins: "paste",
    inline: true, // does not work in mobile
    forced_root_block: true,
    force_br_newlines: false,
    force_p_newlines: false,
    invalid_elements : 'strong,em',
    paste_merge_formats: true,
    paste_preprocess: (plugin: any, args: any) => {
      console.log("que trae",args.content);
      console.log(">>>>>>>>", args.content.split('</p>'));
    },
    paste_word_valid_elements: 'b,strong,i,em,h1,h2',

  }```
````

Comment: Can you create a TinyMCE fiddle with your setup and some initial content that shows these setting are being ignored?  What version of TinyMCE are you using?  Several of those configuration options seem to be for older versions of TinyMCE that we no longer support - today TinyMCE 5.x is the only supported release of TinyMCE.

Comment: @Michael Fromin the link i left serves as a fiddle, i'm using 5.8.2 version, so i think it should work... Thanks for your help! :D